# Netbeans дебагинг проекта созданного из исходников компилируемого через cmake (g++ и C++)

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake

Как прописать cmake что бы он запускался в режиме построчного дебагинга в ide NetBeans ? Сейчас я для этого добавляю флаг -g следующим образом :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")
```

и тогда все работает как следует. Однако это не очень удобно. Может можно как то через меню настроить раздельную компиляцию ? или же к примеру за раз компилировать и релиз и дебаг версии и как то через меню добавить выбор запускаемого проекта НЕ в режиме дебагинга и В режиме дебагинга ?

Answer (score 1):

В `cmake` можно указывать тип сборки. Чаще всего это: `Release` или `Debug` - ide работающие с `cmake` по идее должны о них "знать". Сами по себе они ничего не делают, но вы можете настраивать свой проект в зависимости от того, с каким типом был запущен `cmake`. К примеру я в проектах часто использую один и тотже `build.cmake` файл (по средствам `include`), который выглядит примерно так:

```
# build.cmake

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

if(NOT DEFINED BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL Debug)
  enable_testing()
  include(CTest)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -g -O0")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

Таким образом, когда я запущу `cmake` с опцией `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, то программа (или библиотека) будет скомпилирована без оптимизаций и с отладочной информацией. И это стандартный подход в `cmake`.

Comment: Благодарю вас, попробую сделать подобное